# Check if Array is sorted in Log(N)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I heard that it's possible with some divide and conquer algorithm to check if an array is sorted in Log(N). The fastest way I know is O(N) (just running through the list and checking if element is greater than previous).

I looked online and couldn't find anything, but I thought to ask here if anyone knew before giving up.

Comment: Hearsay. Now, if there was *(unlimited) parallelism* and array contents didn't need to be communicated…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To check if an array is sorted with no previous knowledge, you need to look at all elements at least once, so O(n) is the minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Impossible.  You have to look at every element.