# How to know if an array is sorted?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, statistics

I already read this post but the answer didn't satisfied me [Check if Array is sorted in Log(N)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752241/check-if-array-is-sorted-in-logn).

Imagine I have a serious big array over 1,000,000 **`double`** numbers (positive and/or negative) and I want to know if the array is "sorted" trying to avoid the max numbers of comparisons because comparing doubles and floats take too much time. Is it possible to use statistics on It?, and if It was:

1. It is well seen by real-programmers?
2. Should I take samples?
3. How many samples should I take
4. Should they be random, or in a sequence?
5. How much is the %error permitted to say *`"the array sorted"`*?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Well, it's O(n) and the answer you link to is fine. What you really need to get on top of is why that answer did not satisfy you. The problem is not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic probability problem taught in high school. Consider [this question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081119152814AAdCP5X):

> What is the probability that the batch will be rejected?
>   In a batch of 8,000, clocks 7% are defective. A random sample of 10 (without replacement) from the 8,000 is selected and tested. If at least one is defective the entire batch will be rejected.

So you can take a number of random samples from your large array and see if it's sorted, but you must note that you need to know **the probability that the sample is out of order**. Since you don't have that information, a probabilistic approach wouldn't work efficiently here.

(However, you can check 50% of the array and naively conclude that there is a 50% chance that it is sorted correctly.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i didn't figured of calculating the probability of being sorted.

Comment: If all numbers are distinct and all permutations equally probable, then the chance that a sample of size 2 is sorted is 50%. So if you take k randomly selected pairs and check if they are in expected order, one should incorretly assume a not sorted array to be sorted only with probability of roughly (1/2)^k.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your requirements. If you can say that if 100 random samples out of 1.000.000 is enough the assume it's sorted - then so it is. But to be absolutely sure, you will always have to go through every single entry. Only you can answer this question since only you know how certain you need to be about it being sorted.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a divide and conquer algorithm using multiprocessing (real parallelism, so only for multi-core CPUs) you can check whether an array is sorted or not in Log(N).

If you have GPU multiprocessing you can achieve Log(N) very easily since modern graphics card are able to run few thousands processes in parallel.

Comment: That's not really O(Log(N)), since you have only a finite number of processors.

Comment: you're right, but you reduce the execution time considerably.

Comment: For P processors, the best i can do is O(N/P). see [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

Answer (score 1):

Your question 5 is the question that you need to answer to determine the other answers. To ensure the array is perfectly sorted you must go through every element, because any one of them could be the one out of place.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of comparisons to decide whether the array is sorted is N-1, because there are N-1 adjacent number pairs to compare. But for simplicity, we'll say N as it does not matter if we look at N or N+1 numbers.

Furthermore, it is unimportant where you start, so let's just start at the beginning.
Comparison #1 (A[0] vs. A[1]). If it fails, the array is unsorted. If it succeeds, good.

As we only compare, we can reduce this to the neighbors and whether the left one is smaller or equal (1) or not (0). So we can treat the array as a sequence of 0's and 1's, indicating whether two adjacent numbers are in order or not.

Calculating the error rate or the propability (correct spelling?) we will have to look at all combinations of our 0/1 sequence. 
I would look at it like this: We have 2^n combinations of an array (i.e. the order of the pairs, of which only one is sorted (all elements are 1 indicating that each A[i] is less or equal to A[i+1]).

Now this seems to be simple:
initially the error is 1/2^N. After the first comparison half of the possible combinations (all unsorted) get eliminated. So the error rate should be 1/2^n + 1/2^(n-1).

I'm not a mathematician, but it should be quite easy to calculate how many elements are needed to reach the error rate (find x such that ERROR >= sum of 1/2^n + 1/2^(n-1)... 1/^(2-x) )

Sorry for the confusing english. I come from germany..

Comment: This is a good answer but I don't think the question wanted to *meet* an error rate; rather, it wanted to determine the likelihood of an error. +1 anyways though.

Comment: Well, I just came back from work ... You are correct, not really the answer to the question. But with my idea, you can still determine the error rate after X comparison: error rate = Sum (1/2^n + 1/2^(n-1)... 1/2^(n-x))... or x-1 or so...

Comment: I would approach it like this: if all numbers ai are distinct and all permutations are equally probable, then the probability that a randomly chosen pair (ai,aj) is in sorted order (i.e. `ai < aj`) is `1/2`. Now if the array is not sorted and you do `k` such pair tests, the probability that all checks are ok (and you do not detect that the array is not sorted) is (approximately) `(1/2)^k`. Only approximately, because after some time the checks need not be independent any more: if you have checked `ai1 < ai2` and `ai2 < ai3` then you should not be surprised to find that `ai1 < ai3` holds ...

Comment: Anyway, for k << n the approximation `(1/2)^k`should be good enough. Hence for making sure your error rate is less than `eps` you need `-ld(eps)` pair checks. To bring your error rate below 1% you need 7 pair checks.

Answer (score 0):

Since every single element can be the one element that is out-of-line, you have to run through all of them, hence your algorithm has runtime O(n).

If your understanding of "sorted" is less strict, you need to specify what exaclty you mean by "sorted".  Usually, "sorted" means that adjacent elements meet a less or less-or-equal condition.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else says, the only way to be 100% sure that it is sorted is to run through every single element, which is O(N).

However, it seems to me that if you're so worried about it being sorted, then maybe having it sorted to begin with is more important than the array elements being stored in a contiguous portion in memory?

What I'm getting at is, you could use a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) whose elements by definition follow a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). In other words, the elements in a map are always sorted. You could also use a [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) to achieve the same effect.

For example: `std::map<int,double> collectoin;` would allow you to almost use it like an array: `collection[0]=3.0; std::cout<<collection[0]<<std:;endl;`. There are differences, of course, but if the sorting is so important then an array is the wrong choice for storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

The old fashion way.Print it out and see if there in order. Really if your sort is wrong you would probably see it soon. It's more unlikely that you would only see a few misorders if you were sorting like 100+ things. When ever I deal with it my whole thing is completely off or it works.

Answer (score 0):

As an example that you probably should not use but demonstrates sampling size:

Statistically valid sample size can give you a reasonable estimate of sortedness. If you want to be 95% certain eerything is sorted you can do that by creating a list of truly random points to sample, perhaps ~1500.

Essentially this is completely pointless if the list of values being out of order in one single place will break subsequent algorithms or data requirements.

If this is a problem, preprocess the list before your code runs, or use a really fast sort package in your code.  Most sort packages also have a validation mode, where it simply tells you yes, the list meets your sort criteria - or not.  Other suggestions like parallelization of your check with threads are great ideas.